# Can't open new document from menu bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a menu bar that loads an item (below). On click I want to open a new document, as if opening it from the File menu. I am using `NSDocumentController` and `newDocument:`, but I get nothing - no errors.

I was getting "no document could be created" error, but I got that resolved by adding a new document type… if that has anything to do with it. Any idea why my document is not opening?

**Updated** With `NSLog` below I can see that the document is created but I can't see it!

```
+ (void)buildMenuWithNotifs {
    NSMenuItem* newNoteItem;
    newNoteItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Note" action:@selector(newNote) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [newNoteItem setTarget:[self class]];
    [sm addItem:newNoteItem];
}

+(void)newNote {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];  //app is running as agent
    NSDocumentController *dc = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
    [dc newDocument:nil];
    NSLog(@"dc: %@", dc);
}
```

**Update 3:**

With this code I get "no error" printed with NSLog. 
NSLog that I am calling from Document's `init` *is* getting called, but `windowControllerDidLoadNib` is still not.

```
KBDocument *d = [[KBDocument alloc] init];
if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"KBDocument" owner:d]) {
    NSLog(@"error");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no error");
}
```

Comment: Are you subclassing NSDocument? Does the result `dc` match the class of your subclass? Is `-makeWindowControllers` called on your document subclass? Does your subclass implement `-windowNibName`? Do your documents appear any other way?

Comment: Yes, I am subclassing NSDocument, and dc is `dc: <NSDocumentController: 0x1002b74c0>`. windowNibName method is there, but I don't have `makeWindowControllers` implemented!

Comment: Above you wrote, "With NSLog below I can see that the document is created but I can't see it." I guess I thought you meant the line where you NSLog `dc`, but I realize that isn't the document. Could you clarify what you mean about the document getting created?

Comment: I *was* talking about the NSLog dc, and you're right, it's not a test of whether or not it's loaded. PS. My documents don't appear in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally know what the issue was - In my .plist, I initially deleted the Document types key because I didn't need it. When I recreated it, it defaulted to NSDocument class. I had to change that key value to my own subclass name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code which might help you troubleshoot this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
KBDocument *document = [dc openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:YES error:&error];
NSLog(@"document: %@ error: %@", document, error);
```

I also suggest adding NSLog's in `-[KBDocument init]` and `-[KBDocument windowControllerDidLoadNib:]` to find out if those are getting called.

Comment: I tested with your code, my KBDocument is not getting instantiated, error is null. However, if I try to load it this way (see Update 3)…